# Can I teach ReSharper a custom null check?

Tags: c#, resharper

ReSharper is clever enough to know that a `string.Format` requires a not-null `format` argument so it warns me about it when I simply write

```
_message = string.Format(messageFormat, args);
```

where `messageFormat` can indeed be null. As soon as I add a condition for this variable:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(messageFormat))
{
    _message = string.Format(messageFormat, args);
}
```

the warning disappears. Unfortunately it doesn't when I use an extension method:

```
if (messageFormat.IsNotNullOrEmpty())
{
    _message = string.Format(messageFormat, args); // possible 'null' assignment warning
}
```

My question is: is there a way to *teach* ReSharper that my extension method has the same meaning as `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(messageFormat)`?

The extension is defined as:

```
public static bool IsNotNullOrEmpty([CanBeNull] this string value) => !IsNullOrEmpty(value);
```

Comment: Does this work?

``static string EmptyIfNull(this string s)
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ? "" : s;
}``

then

``_message = string.Format(messageFormat.EmptyIfNull(), args);``

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes there is. You need to use the [ReSharper annotations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Analysis__Code_Annotations.html) to guide ReSharper's analysis. You're already using `[CanBeNull]` so they're already defined in your project.

The one you'll be interested in is [`ContractAnnotationAttribute`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Contract_Annotations.html):

> Contract annotations let you define expected outputs for given inputs, or put in other words, define dependencies between reference type and boolean arguments of a function and its return value. The mechanism of contract annotations allows creating APIs that could be consumed in easier and safer way.

This is how you use it:

```
[ContractAnnotation("null => false")]
public static bool IsNotNullOrEmpty(this string value)
    => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value);
```

The argument is a map of possible inputs (`null`, `notnull`, `true`, `false`) to outputs (`null`, `notnull`, `canbenull`, `true`, `false`, `halt`):

Here's another example:

```
[ContractAnnotation("foo: null => halt; bar: notnull => notnull")]
public string Frob(string foo, string bar)
```

Means that the decorated function will never return (or throw an exception) if you pass it `null` to the `foo` parameter, and guarantees that it won't return `null` if you pass a non-null value to `bar`.

[The documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Contract_Annotations.html) describes the syntax in more detail.

---

Here's what happens without the attribute:

[image: before]

The warning disappears after you add it:

[image: after]

Comment: This looks great! I was using `ContractAnnotation`s here and there already but I didn't know it would work for this case too. I also think this contract is not entirely correct as `notnull` does not necessarily mean `true`. It could be `string.Empty` which is `notnull` but `false` anyway.

Comment: @t3chb0t oops, you're correct, the contract is wrong, `null => false` is enough

Comment: Is this only possible for a method or could a new "null checking pattern" be created using the new expression (X is Type VarName)? I strongly prefer this for nullable types because it makes the code a lot more defensive and intuitive and leaves no room for human error and runtime exceptions.

Comment: @Preza8 from what I can tell ReSharper already handles this by itself.